# Python multiprocessing with starmap and issue with __main__

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, entry-point

I was trying to make small multiprocessing with multiple parameters

**TaskType-1:**

```
import multiprocessing  as mp
import pandas as pd
import os,sys
print("Libs Loaded..!!! ")
listoflists = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,10],[10,11,13,14]]
listoftuples = [tuple(i) for i in listoflists]
print("Length of Tuples : ",len(listoftuples))

def map_function(combo):
    a = combo[0]
    b = combo[1]
    c = combo[2]
    print((a + b + c))
    return (a + b + c)

def doit():
    try:
        print("IN main")
        p = mp.Pool(processes=2)
        # results= p.map(map_function, listoftuples)
        results = p.starmap(map_function,listoftuples)
        print(results)
        print("Done!!")
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)

# if '__name__' == '__main__': 
doit()     # running without entry point
```

**Error for TaskType-1:**

```
Libs Loaded..!!!
Length of Tuples :  4
IN main
Libs Loaded..!!!
Length of Tuples :  4
IN main
<class 'RuntimeError'> testformp.py 20
<class 'TypeError'> testformp.py 22
Libs Loaded..!!!
Length of Tuples :  4
IN main
<class 'RuntimeError'> testformp.py 20
```

Not sure this runtime Error and why it goes in into doit() function multiple times. Multipeprocessing is defined within this function but here it is calling the parent function again and again..Not sure what I am missing here to understand?

**TaskType-2:**

```
if '__name__' == '__main__':
    doit()  # running from entry point
```

**output for TaskType-2:**

```
Libs Loaded..!!!
Length of Tuples :  4
```

It shows no errors nor it performs any task inside. Why this is so?

Comment: Did you mean: `if __name__ == '__main__':`? Otherwise `doit()` will never run.

Comment: Also the `TypeError` comes from the way `starmap()` handles the arguments parameter. You might have meant to have: `def map_function(*combo):` Hence the *star*map

Comment: @quamrana , even if I do get parameters with (*combo) still that runtime error exist? can you explain me in bit detail? and if I run my script within if __name__ == '__main__' : doit() , then doit function is not starting the multiprocessing part?why is it so?

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: @madhureddy, its Python 3.7.3

Answer (score 1):

Making the two changes I suggested I end up with this:

```
import multiprocessing  as mp
import os,sys
#print("Libs Loaded..!!! ")
listoflists = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,10],[10,11,13,14]]
listoftuples = [tuple(i) for i in listoflists]
#print("Length of Tuples : ",len(listoftuples))

def map_function(*combo):
    a = combo[0]
    b = combo[1]
    c = combo[2]
    #print((a + b + c))
    return (a + b + c)

def doit():
    try:
        print("IN main")
        p = mp.Pool(processes=2)
        #results= p.map(map_function, listoftuples)
        results = p.starmap(map_function,listoftuples)
        print(results)
        print("Done!!")
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doit()     # running without entry point
```

And the output is this:

```
IN main
[6, 15, 24, 34]
Done!!
```